# Where are assemblies loaded in a C# application?

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing an application which deals with multiple libraries, and on the odd occasion, there will be a fail in accessing these libraries (DLL missing etc).

The problem at the present time though, is that I can't handle this correctly. When the application loads, if the DLL doesn't exist, the program crashes (Which is understandable). I was wondering what the best approach to combat this is? Is there a way for me to overwrite the way the assemblies are loaded to download these assemblies where missing? Or would I need to manually load all assemblies to combat this?

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer, but you can use dependency manager `Nuget` within VS's `Package Manager Console` to load dependencies and libraries into your solution

Comment: Sorry, this may not have been clear - This is in production and, so the package manager wouldn't help. This is in regards to the executable file itself, rather than within the IDE.

Comment: Check what libraries you need in the application, and ensure that they are always installed in the application's directory?

Comment: check the output directory and make sure they exist. one thing you might find helpful is the Copy Local setting in the reference properties

Comment: Some kind of bootstrapper might help. Checks assemblies and downloads if some missing.

Comment: I'd be more concerned why my assemblies just went missing in a production environment than how to work around it.

Comment: Why not prevent the problem from happening in the first place by baking all of your loose dependencies straight into your executable with a tool such as Fody Costura (or ILMerge if you're feeling brave). That way there's no DLL hell, assemblies never go out of sync *and* you get single-file deployment if you play your cards right.

Comment: In regards to making sure the assemblies are always in directory - I can't disclose the exact reason as to why the assemblies aren't always there, but there's a chance. I can't combat the cause of it, so I'm attempting to implement a method which works around it. Thanks for the thoughts, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign your handler to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to get notified about failed assembly resolution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx